# Can IIS Express 7.5 run multiple sites/appools defined in applicationhost.config?

Tags: iis, configuration, iis-7.5, website

I've defined 2 sites in the corresponding applicationhost.config file and try run them using IIS Express from the command line. Unfortunately I'm only able to start one site at the time.

My 2 questions:
1. Is it possible at all to run multiple sites with IIS Express from one command line?
2. Can IIS run "only" one appool per IIS instance?

Comment: Found the official Microsoft Website "Running IIS Express from the Command Line" but unfortunately it doesn't answer my question: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/870/running-iis-express-from-the-command-line/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I've got a solution for my problem:

If you want to run multiple sites, make sure that they both use same application pool and then use '/apppool' command line swith.

Example: iisexpress /apppool:"Clr4IntegratedAppPool"

Above command would run all the sites that are using 'Clr4IntegratedAppPool' application pool.

But the second question remains open: **Can IIS run "only" one appool per IIS instance?**

Update: Answer to the second question is: Yes, only one appool per IIS instance.

Comment: how did you find out iisexpress.exe supports that /apppool switch?  I had no idea about it, and it's not in any docs I've seen.